# Sharing data between softirq and process context

Tags: c, linux-kernel, locking, netfilter, softirq

I am developing a kernel module that shares data structures between a softirq (netfilter pre-routing hook) and a user context (within an ioctl call).

After reading this [link](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/rusty/kernel-locking/x137.html), I know I need to disable the software interrupts in the user context when modifying the data (using either `spin_lock_bh` or `spin_lock_irqsave`) and re-enable them once the operations on the share data are completed.

However, I am un-sure whether I need to grab the lock in the softirq handler function. 
Do I need to grab the lock here as well (with spin_lock) ?

It is my understanding that I only need to use a spin lock in a softirq handler if sharing data with another softirq or hardirq. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must obtain a lock if you sharing data with any code, which can be executed on the same time. Kernel might execute both your softirq and your ioctl handler, so you **must** obtain a lock.

When you disable interrupts with either `spin_lock_bh` or `spin_lock_irqsave`, interrupts are disabled on current processor only. So, it's OK to handle interrupts on another one.